# How can I put one number in front of another in the style of an LCD clock?

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating a number in the style of lcd clocks.

[image]

I would like to know how I can put one number in front of another. for example I would like to show 123.

[image]

but I do not know how to do it. thank you very much.

```
 <div id="preformatted">

 </div>

 <div class="number-entry-pane">
 <label>Enter a digit:
 <input type="number" id="numInput" min=0 max=9 /></label>

  // Save references to my two control elements.
  var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
  var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");

  // Create an array of the numbers 0 through 9 as 7 segment digits.
  var numberStrings = [
   " __ <br/>|  |<br/>|__|<br/> ",
   "    <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
   " __ <br/> __|<br/>|__ <br/>",
   " __ <br/> __|<br/> __|<br/>",
   "    <br/>|__|<br/>   |<br/>",
   " __ <br/>|__ <br/> __|<br/>",
   " __ <br/>|__ <br/>|__|<br/>",
   " __ <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
   " __ <br/>|__|<br/>|__|<br/>",
   " __ <br/>|__|<br/> __|<br/>"];

  console.log(numberStrings)
  // Attach the listeners for the input changes.
  numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
  numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

  function changeNumbers(){
    // Simply use the element from the array associated with
    //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
    myPre.innerHTML = numberStrings[numInput.value];
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5e1dnt8m/

My idea is not to use several divs.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, but I would assume you want to use multiple divs since your logic supports one. So have a div for each character and output each digit of the clock to the div.

Comment: I add new details. thank you...My idea is not to use several divs.

Comment: With multiple divs you barely would have to change anything, not sure what the fear of that would be. But since you said you do not want to do that, than  you need to change you logic so you somehow can produce multiple lines. You basically need to look at an array and concatenating to it to build each row of strings.

Comment: @epascarello Could you help me with an example with your idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution, it will work. I have removed the `max` limit on the input for testing with bigger numbers.

```js
// Save references to my two control elements.
var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");

// Create an array of the numbers 0 through 9 as 7 segment digits.
var numberStrings = [
 " __ <br/>|  |<br/>|__|<br/> ",
 "    <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
 " __ <br/> __|<br/>|__ <br/>",
 " __ <br/> __|<br/> __|<br/>",
 "    <br/>|__|<br/>   |<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__ <br/> __|<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__ <br/>|__|<br/>",
 " __ <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__|<br/>|__|<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__|<br/> __|<br/>"];

// Attach the listeners for the input changes.
numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

function changeNumbers(){
  // Simply use the element from the array associated with
  //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
  var digits = numInput.value.split('');
  var line=['','',''];
  for (i in digits) {
   var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
    line[0] += numString[0];
    line[1] += numString[1];
    line[2] += numString[2];
  }
  myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
}
```

```css
#preformatted {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="preformatted"></div>

<div class="number-entry-pane">
  <label>Enter a digit:
<input type="number" id="numInput" min=0  />
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001713/modify-the-size-of-the-numbers-im-showing-monospace-style