# modify the size of the numbers I'm showing monospace style

Tags: javascript

I am generating a number in the style of lcd clocks.

[image]

I am somewhat tangled. I want the numbers I show to have a certain size from 1 to 10. For that I put a dropdown with a range of 1 to 10. How can I modify my code so that when choosing a size the numbers (I mean add more _ and more | to show the numbers of a larger size) are updated and they are in the new size?

```
<div id="preformatted"></div>

<div class="number-entry-pane">
  <label>Enter a digit:
<input type="number" id="numInput" min=0  />
size
  </label>

<select id='size'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>
</div>

// Save references to my two control elements.
var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
var size=1;

// Create an array of the numbers 0 through 9 as 7 segment digits.
var numberStrings = [
 " __ <br/>|  |<br/>|__|<br/> ",
 "    <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
 " __ <br/> __|<br/>|__ <br/>",
 " __ <br/> __|<br/> __|<br/>",
 "    <br/>|__|<br/>   |<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__ <br/> __|<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__ <br/>|__|<br/>",
 " __ <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__|<br/>|__|<br/>",
 " __ <br/>|__|<br/> __|<br/>"];

// Attach the listeners for the input changes.
numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

function changeNumbers(){
  // Simply use the element from the array associated with
  //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
  var digits = numInput.value.split('');
  var line=['','',''];
  for (i in digits) {
    var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
    line[0] += numString[0];
    line[1] += numString[1];
    line[2] += numString[2];
  }
  myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
}
```

this is my code. How can do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/hvw5ae05/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not working. Also try to write the code using runnable code snippets provided by stackover. This will allow to test and answer your questions without leaving stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: sorry. this is the new link https://jsfiddle.net/hvw5ae05/  I promise you that next time I will learn

Answer (score 0):

Add an  `change` event to the select, get its value on change and set this value to `fontSize` style property

```js
var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
var size = 1;

// Create an array of the numbers 0 through 9 as 7 segment digits.
var numberStrings = [
  " __ <br/>|  |<br/>|__|<br/> ",
  "    <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
  " __ <br/> __|<br/>|__ <br/>",
  " __ <br/> __|<br/> __|<br/>",
  "    <br/>|__|<br/>   |<br/>",
  " __ <br/>|__ <br/> __|<br/>",
  " __ <br/>|__ <br/>|__|<br/>",
  " __ <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
  " __ <br/>|__|<br/>|__|<br/>",
  " __ <br/>|__|<br/> __|<br/>"
];

// Attach the listeners for the input changes.
numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

function changeNumbers() {
  // Simply use the element from the array associated with
  //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
  var digits = numInput.value.split('');
  var line = ['', '', ''];
  for (i in digits) {
    var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
    line[0] += numString[0];
    line[1] += numString[1];
    line[2] += numString[2];
  }
  myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
}
// Added new eventhandler onchange of dropdown value
document.getElementById('size').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  myPre.style.fontSize = this.value + "px"
})
```

```html
<div id="preformatted"></div>

<div class="number-entry-pane">
  <label>Enter a digit:
        <input type="number" id="numInput" min=0  />
        size
    </label>

  <select id='size'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I have added an `change` event listener for the size dropdown and created a function that modifies the font size based on the value selected. The height of the bounding box will also be scaled.

```js
    // Save references to my two control elements.
    var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
    var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
    var sizeInput = document.getElementById("size");
    var size=1;

    // Create an array of the numbers 0 through 9 as 7 segment digits.
    var numberStrings = [
     " __ <br/>|  |<br/>|__|<br/> ",
     "    <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
     " __ <br/> __|<br/>|__ <br/>",
     " __ <br/> __|<br/> __|<br/>",
     "    <br/>|__|<br/>   |<br/>",
     " __ <br/>|__ <br/> __|<br/>",
     " __ <br/>|__ <br/>|__|<br/>",
     " __ <br/>   |<br/>   |<br/>",
     " __ <br/>|__|<br/>|__|<br/>",
     " __ <br/>|__|<br/> __|<br/>"];

    // Attach the listeners for the input changes.
    numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
    numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);
    sizeInput.addEventListener("change", changeSize);

    function changeNumbers(){
      // Simply use the element from the array associated with
      //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
      var digits = numInput.value.split('');
      var line=['','',''];
      for (i in digits) {
        var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
        line[0] += numString[0];
        line[1] += numString[1];
        line[2] += numString[2];
      }
      myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
    }
    
    function changeSize() {
      var scalingFactor = 5;
      myPre.style['font-size'] = (12 +((this.value-1)*scalingFactor))+'px';
      myPre.style.height = (50 +((this.value-1)*scalingFactor*3.5))+'px';
    }
```

```css
    #preformatted {
        font-family: monospace;
        white-space: pre;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px dotted red;
        width: 500px;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="preformatted"></div>

    <div class="number-entry-pane">
      <label>Enter a digit:
    <input type="number" id="numInput" min=0  />
    size
      </label>

    <select id='size'>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

You can experiment with different values for `scalingFactor` to obtain better results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I think I made myself misunderstand. I'm trying to put more _ and | to make the numbers bigger. Each digit must occupy exactly size + 2 columns and 2 * size + 3 rows.

Comment: I will add a bounty so please help me. you are very smart!

Comment: @yavg Try adding a bounty, someone might find a better solution for you. But do remember, this is not a place where you can make others do your work.
Do your research, try something and when you get stuck, come here.