# How can I do to show a string that draws one number in front of another?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show zero numbers for now. then when I enter the number zero in the text field, the zero number formed by "|" and "_".

[image]

my problem is that I do not know how to put several zero numbers together, in the same line. how can I do it?

for example if I write "00"
this should to show:

[image]

this is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/9oepptbj/

```
// Save references to my two control elements.
var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
var size=2;


// Attach the listeners for the input changes.
numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

function changeNumbers(){
  // Simply use the element from the array associated with
  //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
  var digits = numInput.value.split('');
  //var line=['','','', '', '', '', ''];
  var line=[];
  for(var i=0; i<(size*2)+1; i++)
  {
   line.push('');
  }
  for (i in digits) {
  console.log(digits)
    //var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
    var numString=" ";
    switch(parseInt(i)) {
      case 0:
       for(var a=0; a<(size);a++)
       {
        numString+="_ "
       }
       numString+="<br/>";
       for(var a=0; a<(size*2)-1;a++)
       {
        //lateral izquierdo
        numString+="|";
        for(var e=0; e<(size*2)-1; e++)
        {
           numString+=" ";
        }
        //se quita último espacio
        numString+="|<br/>";
       }   
       //cerrando parte de abajo
       numString+="|";
       for(var a=0; a<(size);a++)
       {
        numString+="_ "
       }
       numString= numString.slice(0, - 1);
       numString+="|";
      break;
    }
    numString=numString.split('<br/>');
    console.log(numString)
    for(var i=0; i<(size*2)+1; i++)
    {
      line[i] += numString[i];
    }
  }
  myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
}
```

how can do it?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001398/how-can-i-put-one-number-in-front-of-another-in-the-style-of-an-lcd-clock)?

Comment: @Amy Thanks for your interest. I'm doing the numbers dynamically. I put a size and the number zero is generated with that size. therefore logic varies and I am not able to achieve what I want. for now the only number I have done is zero, but I hope to do the same with the others.

Answer (score 1):

define `i = 0;` in `for loop`

```js
// Save references to my two control elements.
var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
var size = 2;


// Attach the listeners for the input changes.
numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

function changeNumbers() {
  // Simply use the element from the array associated with
  //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
  var digits = numInput.value.split('');
  //var line=['','','', '', '', '', ''];
  var line = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (size * 2) + 1; i++) {
    line.push('');
  }
  for (i in digits) {
   // console.log(digits)
    i = 0;
    //var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
    var numString = " ";
    switch (parseInt(i)) {
      case 0:
        for (var a = 0; a < (size); a++) {
          numString += "_ "
        }
        numString += "<br/>";
        for (var a = 0; a < (size * 2) - 1; a++) {
          //lateral izquierdo
          numString += "|";
          for (var e = 0; e < (size * 2) - 1; e++) {
            numString += " ";
          }
          //se quita último espacio
          numString += "|<br/>";
        }
        //cerrando parte de abajo
        numString += "|";
        for (var a = 0; a < (size); a++) {
          numString += "_ "
        }
        numString = numString.slice(0, -1);
        numString += "|";
        break;
    }
    numString = numString.split('<br/>');
   // console.log(numString)
    for (var i = 0; i < (size * 2) + 1; i++) {
      line[i] += numString[i];
    }
  }
  myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
}
```

```css
#preformatted {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  __text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="preformatted"></div>

<div class="number-entry-pane">
  <label>Enter a digit:
<input type="number" id="numInput" min=0  />
  </label>


</div>
```

Comment: oh! what a solution? you should find the actual error and correct it, not just simply set i to 0 in the loop. when the unusuario code completes and consider drawing other digits like 1,2,3... this workaround will not be the solution!

Comment: but in case it only check 0 not for other digits @S.Serp so dont be lecturer

Comment: its not a good idea to think this way in coding! It will raise more hidden errors later when he/she develop his code. By the way, why you search and down-vote my other posts without even reading them at single moment?! it is not nice

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is due to the `for-in` loop in java script. When you write `for (i in digits)` and digits is an array like ["0", "0", "0", ...], you will get index of items (0, 1, 2, ...) in `i` not their values! so you have to change this in your code:

```
switch(parseInt(i)) {
```

to:

```
switch(parseInt(digits[i])) {
```

```js
// Save references to my two control elements.
var myPre = document.getElementById("preformatted");
var numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
var size = 2;


// Attach the listeners for the input changes.
numInput.addEventListener("keyup", changeNumbers);
numInput.addEventListener("change", changeNumbers);

function changeNumbers() {
  // Simply use the element from the array associated with
  //  the entered number to update the preformatted display.
  var digits = numInput.value.split('');
  //var line=['','','', '', '', '', ''];
  var line = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (size * 2) + 1; i++) {
    line.push('');
  }
  for (i in digits) {
    // console.log(digits)
    //var numString = numberStrings[digits[i]].split('<br/>');
    var numString = " ";
    switch (parseInt(digits[i])) {
      case 0:
        for (var a = 0; a < (size); a++) {
          numString += "_ "
        }
        numString += "<br/>";
        for (var a = 0; a < (size * 2) - 1; a++) {
          //lateral izquierdo
          numString += "|";
          for (var e = 0; e < (size * 2) - 1; e++) {
            numString += " ";
          }
          //se quita último espacio
          numString += "|<br/>";
        }
        //cerrando parte de abajo
        numString += "|";
        for (var a = 0; a < (size); a++) {
          numString += "_ "
        }
        numString = numString.slice(0, -1);
        numString += "|";
        break;
    }
    numString = numString.split('<br/>');
   // console.log(numString)
    for (var i = 0; i < (size * 2) + 1; i++) {
      line[i] += numString[i];
    }
  }
  myPre.innerHTML = line.join('<br/>');
}

if (numInput.value!="") changeNumbers();
```

```css
#preformatted {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  __text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="preformatted"></div>

<div class="number-entry-pane">
  <label>Enter a digit:
    <input type="number" id="numInput" min=0 value="000"  />
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. FYI, the "undefined " value was due to the  "i"  value in the statement  " for (i in digits) "  being a non-zero value on all iterations after index 0. Since the switch statement only accepted a 0, it worked on the first iteration and failed on all the others. Therefore the case 0 statement never got called  after the first iteration and the numString variable never got declared leading to undefined values in the "line" variable.

Comment: @HelloWorldPeace the original code provided does not include digits other than zero. currently you have to type for example "000" in the textbox to check its implementation. when other digits implemented, they will be shown. (the case 0 statement can be true in all iterations if the given text contains several zeros)

Comment: Correct, i agree. The statement above was not directed towards you. I was just providing more detail for the original poster or anyone else. The answer you provided is what I came up with as well.